# How to use binary search on unsorted array with key and value in java?

Tags: java, arrays, search, binary-search-tree

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class BinarySearchUnsorted {

    int binary(Map<Integer, Integer> map, int start, int end, int x) {
        if (end >= start) {
            int test=start+(end-start);
            int mid = test / 2;
            System.out.println(mid);
            System.out.println(map.get(mid));
            if (map.get(mid) == x) {
                return map.get(mid);
            }
            if (map.get(mid) > x) {
                return binary(map, start, mid - 1, x);
            }
            return binary(map, mid + 1, end, x);
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 3;
        int[] arr = { 2, 4, 3, 8 };
        int length = arr.length;
        
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            map.put(arr[i],i );

        }
        BinarySearchUnsorted ob = new BinarySearchUnsorted();
        int result = ob.binary(map, 0, length - 1, x);
        if (result == -1) {
            System.out.println("Element not present");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Element found at index " + result);
        }
    }
}
```

I have given array of integers added unsorted and integer that I want to find on which position it is. I want to use binary search which use only sorted arrays so I sort the numbers from the array and save their first position. Every help will be good.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what are you trying to do?

Comment: Binary search only works on sorted lists

Comment: https://www.java67.com/2015/01/how-to-sort-hashmap-in-java-based-on.html

Comment: You want to sort the array and than search and return the index?? It will be more efficient to just run over the unsorted array and return the value of that index

Comment: I know that it is used for sorted lists.I need to use binarySearch method using unsorted array.i use map so i can save the index before sorting the array.after i sort the array,i appy binary search so i can fast find the number that i search if i have a lot of numbers in the array.When i found the number i need to output its index that i saved before sorting.If the number that i search doesnt exist the output will be -1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer

```
public static class MyEntry {
        int key;
        int value;

        public MyEntry(Integer k, Integer v) {
            key = k;
            value = v;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return ("(" + key + "," + value + ") ");
        }
    }

    public static int BinSearch(MyEntry[] arr,int low, int high, int k) {
        int  mid;


        mid = (high + low) / 2;

        if (high >= low) {

            if (arr[mid].key == k) {
                return (mid);
            }
            if (arr[mid].key > k) {
                return BinSearch(arr, low, mid - 1, k);
            }
            return BinSearch(arr, mid + 1, high, k);
        }

        return -1;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = { 2, 4, 3, 8 };
        int len = arr.length;
        System.out.println(len + "dulj");
        MyEntry[] entry = new MyEntry[len];

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            entry[i] = new MyEntry(arr[i], i);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < entry.length; i++)
            System.out.print(i + ":" + entry[i]);
        System.out.println();

        int result = BinSearch(entry,0, len-1, 8);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```